# mvc. net core radio buttons to select value for each and model binder

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, radio-button, asp.net-core-3.1, model-binding

I have 4 radio buttons, and I want to select value for each radio buttons and bind them to a model binder so that each property will have a value either true or false. At the moment, we need radio buttons not checkboxes. I need to group them so only one radio button should be selected, rest of them will have a value = false. For example, if I select Yes - Math - the radio button should have a value true for it, and rest them should be false.

So here is my razor view class

```
<div class="radio-class">
                        <input class="radios__input" id="IsMath" name="SubjectRadio" type="radio" value="true">
                        <label class="label" for="IsMath">Yes - Math</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radios__item">
                        <input class="radios__input" id="IsPhysics" name="SubjectRadio" type="radio" value="true">
                        <label class="label" for="IsPhysics">Yes - Physics</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radios__item">
                        <input class="radios__input" id="IsChemistry" name="SubjectRadio" type="radio" value="true">
                        <label class="label" for="IsChemistry">Yes - Chemistry</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radios__item">
                        <input class="radios__input" id="IsNoSubjects" name="SubjectRadio" type="radio" value="true">
                        <label class="label" for="IsNoSubjects">No Subjects</label>
                    </div>
```

Here is my model like this:

```
 [BindProperty]
    public bool? IsPhysics { get; set; } = false;

    [BindProperty]
    public bool? IsChemistry { get; set; } = false;

    [BindProperty]
    public bool? IsMath { get; set; } = false;

    [BindProperty]
    public bool? IsNoSubjects { get; set; } = false;
```

I never get the individual values for it. I want the true value for the one I selectrest of them will be a false value. Can anyone help? I do not want to change a code to radiobutton list at the moment, or If that is the way. However still I need to pass true and false to each properties after the selection of radio buttons.

I am using Post method to submit the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model Binding binds the property by `name` attribute instead of `id` attribute. So you need change your code like below:

```
<div class="radio-class">
    <input class="radios__input" name="IsMath" id="SubjectRadio" type="radio" value="true">
    <label class="label" for="IsMath">Yes - Math</label>
</div>
<div class="radios__item">
    <input class="radios__input" name="IsPhysics" id="SubjectRadio" type="radio" value="true">
    <label class="label" for="IsPhysics">Yes - Physics</label>
</div>
<div class="radios__item">
    <input class="radios__input" name="IsChemistry" id="SubjectRadio" type="radio" value="true">
    <label class="label" for="IsChemistry">Yes - Chemistry</label>
</div>
<div class="radios__item">
    <input class="radios__input" name="IsNoSubjects" id="SubjectRadio" type="radio" value="true">
    <label class="label" for="IsNoSubjects">No Subjects</label>
</div>
            
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Besides, not sure your form sends `post` or `get` request, but if you send the `get` request, be sure change the property to `[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]`.

---

A Whole working demo you could follow:

View(Index.cshtml)

```
<form>
    <div class="radio-class">
        <input class="radios__input" name="IsMath" id="SubjectRadio" type="radio" value="true">
        <label class="label" for="IsMath">Yes - Math</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radios__item">
        <input class="radios__input" name="IsPhysics" id="SubjectRadio" type="radio" value="true">
        <label class="label" for="IsPhysics">Yes - Physics</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radios__item">
        <input class="radios__input" name="IsChemistry" id="SubjectRadio" type="radio" value="true">
        <label class="label" for="IsChemistry">Yes - Chemistry</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radios__item">
        <input class="radios__input" name="IsNoSubjects" id="SubjectRadio" type="radio" value="true">
        <label class="label" for="IsNoSubjects">No Subjects</label>
    </div>
                
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>       
</form>
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {            
        return View();        
    }
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet =true)]
    public bool? IsPhysics { get; set; } = false;

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public bool? IsChemistry { get; set; } = false;

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public bool? IsMath { get; set; } = false;

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public bool? IsNoSubjects { get; set; } = false;
}
```

Result

[image]

**Update:**

If you want to make the radio button only selects one option, the name attribute must be the same.

For how to make model binding work, two ways you could follow.

The fist way you can get the reiced value of radio button and manually set the property value:

View

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Create">
    <div class="radio-class">
        <input class="radios__input" id="IsMath" name="SubjectRadio" type="radio" value="IsMath">
        <label class="label" for="IsMath">Yes - Math</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radios__item">
        <input class="radios__input" id="IsPhysics" name="SubjectRadio" type="radio" value="IsPhysics">
        <label class="label" for="IsPhysics">Yes - Physics</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radios__item">
        <input class="radios__input" id="IsChemistry" name="SubjectRadio" type="radio" value="IsChemistry">
        <label class="label" for="IsChemistry">Yes - Chemistry</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radios__item">
        <input class="radios__input" id="IsNoSubjects" name="SubjectRadio" type="radio" value="IsNoSubjects">
        <label class="label" for="IsNoSubjects">No Subjects</label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{            
    return View();        
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(string SubjectRadio)
{
    switch(SubjectRadio)
    {
        case "IsPhysics":
            IsPhysics = true;
            break;
        case "IsChemistry":
            IsChemistry= true;  
            break;
        case "IsMath":
            IsMath= true; break;
        default:IsNoSubjects=true; break;
    }
    return View();
}
[BindProperty(SupportsGet =true)]
public bool? IsPhysics { get; set; } = false;

[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public bool? IsChemistry { get; set; } = false;

[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public bool? IsMath { get; set; } = false;

[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public bool? IsNoSubjects { get; set; } = false;
```

The second way is that you can use the ajax:

View

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="radio-class">
        <input class="radios__input" id="IsMath" name="SubjectRadio" type="radio">
        <label class="label" for="IsMath">Yes - Math</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radios__item">
        <input class="radios__input" id="IsPhysics" name="SubjectRadio" type="radio">
        <label class="label" for="IsPhysics">Yes - Physics</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radios__item">
        <input class="radios__input" id="IsChemistry" name="SubjectRadio" type="radio">
        <label class="label" for="IsChemistry">Yes - Chemistry</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radios__item">
        <input class="radios__input" id="IsNoSubjects" name="SubjectRadio" type="radio">
        <label class="label" for="IsNoSubjects">No Subjects</label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $('form').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $('input[type=radio][name=SubjectRadio]:checked').attr('id');
            var data;
            switch(id){
                case "IsMath":
                    data = { "IsMath":true}; break;
                case "IsPhysics":
                    data = { "IsPhysics":true}; break;
                case "IsChemistry":
                    data = { "IsChemistry": true }; break;
                default:
                    data = { "IsNoSubjects": true }; break;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Home/Create',
                data: data,
                success: function () {
                    //do your stuff...
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
{            
    return View();        
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create()
{
        
    //...
}
[BindProperty]
public bool? IsPhysics { get; set; } = false;
[BindProperty]
public bool? IsChemistry { get; set; } = false;

[BindProperty]
public bool? IsMath { get; set; } = false;

[BindProperty]
public bool? IsNoSubjects { get; set; } = false;
```

Comment: Let me try this, many thanks - I am using Post method.

Comment: It creates 2 problems. Now, I am able to select all radio buttons, which I do not want - If you check this in your example too, And for some reason - It does not retain the value, perhaps we have changed the Id to name causing it.  Any more bright ideas

Comment: Hi @catcherjavscript, if you want to make the radio button one select and also specify the each radio button value and match with different property, you may need use ajax in js to post the data. As you said, only the same name can make radio button one select, but model binding by default binds the property by name attribute.

Comment: Or you can make radio button with different value like: `value="IsPhysics "`/`value="IsChemistry "`, and receive the string parameter named `SubjectRadio` Manully make this received value property as true.

Comment: Updated with the answer. Pls check.

Comment: Thanks, I used the csharp version of it.